# Specify colors in plotly graph

Tags: python, plotly

I have a plotly line plot and would like to assign specific colors to each line. For example, TSLA = 'blue', AAPL = 'red', etc. This is because I will create multiple scatterplots with various combinations of the entities and would like the color to be consistent.

```py
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.line(df_pivot,  x='Range', y='Mentions', color='Term')
fig.show()
```

Graph shown in image

[image: graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary for the colors with the parameter `color_discrete_map`. For example:

```
import plotly.express as px
q = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,1],[4,5,2],[2,6,2],[3,8,1],[5,1,1]], columns=["Range", "Mentions", 'Term'])
colors_dict = {1:"black", 2:"orange"}

fig = px.line(q,  x='Range', y='Mentions',color='Term', color_discrete_map=colors_dict)
fig.show()
```